# show popup menu when click on button

Tags: android, menu, popupmenu

[image]

I have problem with show popup menu when I click the layout, can any one have experience help me.

I think my problem maybe with my main activity because I use with group view but I don't know how to solve that problem can any body help me

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        context = getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fg_dashboard__product__services, container, false);
        rsview = (RecyclerView)view.findViewById(R.id.dashboard_product_service);


        albumList = new ArrayList<>();
        adapter = new DashboardProductServiceAdapter(context, albumList);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(context, 1);
        rsview.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
//       rsview.addItemDecoration(new GridSpacingItemDecoration(2, dpToPx(10), true));
        rsview.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        rsview.setAdapter(adapter);

        prepareAlbums();
        return view;

    }
```

This is my click action

```
holder.layout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showPopupMenu(holder.layout);
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Click on layout", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

This is my showPopupMenu Function.

```
public void showPopupMenu(View view) {
        PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
        MenuInflater inflater = popup.getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.dashboard_context_menu, popup.getMenu());
        popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new MyMenuItemClickListener());
        popup.show();
    }
```

Comment: what is ur issue,ur code looks fine

Comment: your code is ok please check what you have done in its onclick listener or where you are using this function are you passing the correct button

Comment: Post your error log if you're getting any errors.

Comment: please check error log image attach update

Comment: problem with xml... see the xml where you missing layout_height ..Show you xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found the solution, The problems is not with xml file, it is with java.

I use :

```
android.widget.PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(getApplicationContext(), view);
```

instead of :

```
PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(mContext, view);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem obviously isnt in java code, one of your elements in XML does not have layout_height attribute (probably the popup menu, or some other element in R.menu.dashboard_context_menu). Check this file, line #17 for any code mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define "android:layout_height" attribute in the xml code.